# Cannot convert from object to string

Tags: c#

I am getting an error with the following code:

```
TabPage tmpTabPage = new TabPage(dr["s_adi"]);
```

The Error message is:

> Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Full code:

```
try
{
    if (bag.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        bag.Open();

    string query = "SELECT * FROM [masa]";
    SqlCommand kmt = new SqlCommand(query, bag);
    SqlDataReader dr;
    dr = kmt.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        TabPage tmpTabPage = new TabPage(dr["s_adi"]);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tmpTabPage);
    }
    bag.Close();
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Salon listesi çekilirken hata oluştu.");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `dr["s_adi"]` with `Convert.ToString(dr["s_adi"])` or `dr.GetString("s_adi")`?

Comment: Convert.ToString(dr["s_adi"]) Thanks. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
TabPage tmpTabPage = new TabPage(dr["s_adi"]);
```

You need to convert

```
dr["s_adi"]
```

to a string explicitly. There is no way to implicitly convert something of type object to a string.